# Обработка строк через преобразование в массив в Java

Tags: java, массивы, строки, split

Всем привет!
В данный момент я решаю следующую задачу:
нужно реализовать публичный статический метод **makeCensored()**, который заменяет каждое вхождение указанного слова в предложении на последовательность **$#%!** и возвращает полученную строку.

**Аргументы:**

- Текст
- Стоп-слово

Словом считается любая непрерывная последовательность символов, включая любые спецсимволы (без пробелов)

**Как программа должна работать:**

```
var text1 = "When you play the game of thrones, you win or you die";

String[] stopWords1 = {"die", "play"};

var result1 = MyStringUtils.makeCensored(text1, stopWords1);

System.out.println(result1);

// => "When you $#%! the game of thrones, you win or you $#%!"

var text2 = "chicken chicken? chicken! chicken";

String[] stopWords2 = {"?", "chicken"};

var result2 = MyStringUtils.makeCensored(text2, stopWords2);

System.out.println(result2);

// => "$#%! chicken? chicken! $#%!
```

**Указания к задаче:**

- Разбить строку на массив слов можно при помощи метода **split()**
- Обратно собрать строку из массива можно при помощи метода **join()**
- Для проверки вхождения строки в массив используйте метод **ArrayUtils.contains()**;

```
String[] words = {"hello", "world"};

ArrayUtils.contains(words, "hello"); // true

ArrayUtils.contains(words, "Jack"); // false
```

**Моя попытка решения выглядит следующим образом:**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class MyStringUtils{

     public static void main(String[] args){
    }
    
    public static String makeCensored(String text, String[] stopWords){
      
      var words= text.split("");
      String sequence="$#%!";

      for(int i=0; i<words.length;i++){
          words[i] = ArrayUtils.contains(stopwords, sequence);
      }

      return String.join(" ", StopWords);
   
   }
}
```

Мне интересно услышать Ваши идеи и предложения по поводу этой задачи.

Comment: По вашему коду выходит, что вы в цикле ищете sequence в массиве стоп-слов, а потом склеиваете стоп-слова через пробел в одну строку. Это же явно не то, что требуется.

Comment: @Nofate, а что если переписать так?


`import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;`

`public class MyStringUtils{`

` var words=text.split(" ");`

    ` StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(stopWords);`

     `for(var word:words){`

         `if(joiner.(ArrayUtils.contains(words, stopWords))){`

            ` joiner.add("$#%!");`

         `}else{`

             `joiner.add(word);`

       `  }`

     }

     `return String.join(" ", joiner);`
      `}`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Спустя несколько дней я все-таки разобрался в данной задаче.

**Первое**,и очень важное : метод **contains() - это статический метод класса ArrayUtils**, то есть он вызывается из класса **ArrayUtils**, а все данные для работы он получает через параметры **ArrayUtils.contains(stopWords, words[i])**.Таким образом,мы проверяем,содержит ли массив **stopWords** элемент **words[i]**

**Второе:** для эффективной конкатенации строк без создания дополнительных экземпляров класса **String** необходимо импортировать класс **java.util.StringJoiner**

**Ниже привожу свое решение:**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class MyStringUtils{
public static String makeCensored(String text, String[] stopWords){

   var words= text.split(" ");
   String sequence="$#%!";
   StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");  

   for(int i=0; i<words.length;i++){
        joiner.add(ArrayUtils.contains(stopWords, words[i])?sequence:words[i]);
   }
   return joiner.toString();
 }
}
```